# How can I position my CSS dropdown so it does not go off screen?

Tags: css, layout

I'm working on a hover dropdown and some of the dropdown content menus flow off the edge of the screen.  I don't have a good solution to ensure that the dropdowns remain on in the visible area of the screen, outside of being a little heavy handed and adding ids to particular dropdowns and positioning them as I see fit.

I've added a snippet below that demonstrates the issue. I've also created a codepen using scss. [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dLBzNz)

What I am expecting is for all of the dropdowns to appear within the boundries of the screen.

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  outline: 5px solid orangered;
}

.container__item {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.container__itemdropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, red, yellow, yellow, red);
  margin: 10px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  opacity: 0;
}

.container__item:hover .container__itemdropdown {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__item">
    <div class="container__itemdropdown"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container__item">
    <div class="container__itemdropdown"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container__item">
    <div class="container__itemdropdown"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container__item">
    <div class="container__itemdropdown"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container__item">
    <div class="container__itemdropdown"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure with scss but a few css tricks you could try are for example:

> container:last-child {
>   float: right
>   }

or

> container{ position: absolute }; container { left: -(someNumber)px };

Hope those two quick fixes help solve the issue!